# VB6 IDE crashes after application terminates

Tags: vb6, ide

Several developers on my team have this problem. We can run our app in the IDE fine, but when we eventually quit the app, *the IDE itself will then crash*.

The crash takes the form of

> "Visual Basic has stopped working"

[image]

It doesn't matter if we quit our app nicely or force-stop it in the debugger; same result (crashed IDE).

---

The exit sequence for the app is:

1. User selects 'exit' from a menu
2. Menu event handler calls `Unload Me`
3. `Form_QueryUnload` event handler fires
4. `Form_Unload` event handler fires. It does:

```
'close all sub forms
For i = Forms.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
    Unload Forms(i)
Next
```

Then saves some data and then does `Exit Sub`.

---

We tend to run a group file with a 5-6 projects in it.

This error sometimes seems to go away, other times it occurs, seemingly randomly. I don't know what factor influences this.

If we don't actually run the app, just the IDE, then it works fine and we can quit the IDE itself normally.

Anyone seen this before? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I have also seen this happen.  Not very often, and seemingly random just like you.  I haven't figured out the solution, either.

Comment: Do you use **any** API hooks to Windows messages in the project? If so, make sure they're only used in the compiled app, _not_ in the IDE.

Comment: Can your share your exit code?

Comment: FWIW, I also find it fascinating that you have a "team" of VB6 developers.  It's nice to hear actually.

Answer (score 6):

This is most definately caused by leaks of VB6 objects that are involved in subclassing/hooking and not only these.

What we did to get rid of these crashes was to instrument all of our classes (including forms, user controls, designers and anything that can be instantiated) with `DebugInstanceInit` and `DebugInstanceTerm` calls in respective Class/Form/UserControl `Initialize` and `Terminate` events.

```
Public Sub DebugInstanceInit(sModuleName As String, sDebugID As String, oObj As Object)

Public Sub DebugInstanceTerm(sModuleName As String, sDebugID As String)
```

These basicly track at any time how many and what kind of instances the application is using. Each instance is assigned a unique `sDebugID` in `DebugInstanceInit` that is used as a key in `DebugIDs` collection. This collection is instantiated empty in `Sub Main` and when application teminates (i.e. in main form's `Form_Unload`) this collection has to be empty or with a fixed number of instances left (for instance exactly 4) otherwise its content is the kind of objects we are leaking.

**What fixed the IDE crashes?**

Notice the collection is instantiated as late as `Sub Main` which means it has to remain `Nothing` at design-time. We just put a simple check in `DebugInstanceInit` like this

```
    If DebugIDs Is Nothing Then
        If Left$(sModuleName, 3) <> "ctx" Then
            DebugPrint "DebugInstanceInit", "mdErrorHandling", sDebugID & " " & LIB_NAME & "." & sModuleName & "." & FUNC_NAME_INITIALIZE & " (This should not happen)"
        End If
    Else
       ...
    End If
```

Basicly this prevented **anything** other than raw UserControls placed on forms from being instantiated at design-time. This includes `GlobalMultiUse` objects, this includes anything UC properties are accessing as UC properties are kind of routines that are certainly accessed at design-time.

So we had to sprinkle most of the UC's code heavily with `Ambient.UserMode` checks like this

```
    If Ambient.UserMode Then
        Set .Picture = LoadStdPicture(ucsPicHelp)
    End If
```

It turned out our `LoadStdPicture` global function was instantiating some `cDibSections` for instance. The nice thing is that once you put a break-point at `(This should not happen)` debug print statement, the call-stack shows you exactly the offenting property of the offending UC.

Comment: I think this answer was on the right track - the problem in my specific program turned out to originate within a third-party OCX library; when I updated it to a more recent version the issue was resolved. Thank you for setting me on the right track.

Comment: Also - I noticed some other similar posts you've made on this topic but I'm not sure if any of them include the entire source of your very useful DebugInstance...() procedures. Perhaps if you add them here (or a link to the full sources) that would be a benefit!

Comment: @DaveInCaz These can be as simple as generating next sequential debug id and adding instance info to a collection with `"#" & sDebugID` as key (two LoC) and then just removing `"#" & sDebugID` key on termination (single LoC). A better sample would be a whole project with instrumented classes and forms and a leak reporting msgbox on app tear-down. . .

Answer (score 0):

I believe [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53002765/3195477) is correct in its technical assessment of the cause of the problem. But it may also be useful to briefly describe the procedure I used to narrow down the source lines of code. In my case this problem appeared to be TOTALLY random, so it was hard to know where to start.

My approach was not rocket science - more brute force. Essentially I used a binary search to rule in/out sections of code. First step was to comment out the entire startup procedure so that the app would start as an empty shell; this demonstrated that the problem went away (null result).

Following that I recursively commented in roughly half the code, testing for the problem each time. Each block was evaluated as a boolean - it either did or did not cause the problem. Then proceed again in the block not ruled out.

Eventually (and more quickly than I anticipated) this led to a single line of code which accessed a property of a third-party control.